# How to remove empty headers from excel file in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I used this function for reading the data from excel file. But in some cases if excel sheet has empty rows in that case we should not read and also it has empty headers stop the process, Please help me Thank you..

[image]

---

```
  $path = Input::file('import_file');

  $data_read = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
    $reader->limit(25);
  })->get();


  $hrs =  Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($path, function($reader){
   $results = $reader->noHeading();         
  })->get();
```

Comment: Do you want to stop processing the file, or to just ignore the empty columns?

Comment: Either stop the process or empty the ignore columns and empty rows.. thanks..

Comment: Columns with no headings have integer keys, so they are easy to ignore. And you can ignore empty rows by checking for `null` data in one or more columns.